# Building a database of average speed from two cameras using cloudant entries

Tags: cloudant, querying

I'm very new to IBM Cloud, and specifically, Cloudant DB. In this database is records of when cars pass two different speed cameras (either 20 or 21). I have a database of javascript objects with the following format:

```
{
  "_id": "006994989f0914a7fb1ca44fae00fe75",
  "_rev": "1-e9b9afcb45f6ff703825d4be6d331f73",
  "payload": {
    "license_plate": "GNX834",
    "camera_id": 20,
    "date_time_string": "2019-05-08T15:20:04.134Z",
    "date_time_UTC_milliseconds": 1557328804134
  },
  "qos": 2,
  "retain": false
}
```

I wish create a search index function to create another database full of objects that contain the average speed of cars as they travel between the two cameras (They're 3 miles apart). I know I need to sort them by number plate, but I'm struggling to understand how to do this in Cloudant DB?

Any help on this subject would be great!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to extra the documents where the `licence_plate` is equal to a value that you know, then you need to create an [index on that field](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/Cloudant?topic=cloudant-query):

```
POST /db/_index HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "index": {
    "fields": ["payload.license_plate"]
  },
  "name" : "plate-index",
  "type" : "json"
}
```

Then you can query by licence plate:

```
POST /db/_find HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "selector": {
    "payload.license_plate": "NH67992"
  }
}
```

which would return you the matching documents.

Alternatively, if you want to extract the data *en masse*, ordered by the license plate field, you could create a [MapReduce View](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/Cloudant?topic=cloudant-views-mapreduce) with the license plate as the key (map function below):

```
function(doc) {
  emit(doc.payload.license_plate, doc.payload.date_time_string)
}
```

The index that this Map function generates is ordered by license plate and be used to extract data in license plate order.